# .htaccess file causing a redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My .htaccess file is causing a redirect loop and not sure why!

Here's my current .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Put your installation directory here:
# If your URL is www.example.com/, use /
# If your URL is www.example.com/kohana/, use /kohana/
# RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: No, that's the complete file. It's on a GoDaddy CentOS 6 + cPanel server if that helps any more.

Comment: It can't be your `.htaccess` file - must be something in your PHP app. And I don't think the `PT` flag is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess to avoid looping error:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Do not enable rewriting for files or directories that exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# For reuests that are not actual files or directories,
# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that while using Linux Apache (not quite certain about version anymore), my web worked fine.

However the exactly same code (copy/paste of whole folder containing just static html file and htaccess) did not work while using Windows Apache/2.4.29 (Win64). I had to add the "RewriteBase" tag:

```
RewriteBase /
```

I believe some default values changed and it was being redirected to different folder (where index.html obviously did not exist)